# Number of questions tagged not adding up right

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow, tags, questions

When browsing questions in StackOverflow with a particular tag, and viewing on the `Newest` tab, on the top-right, there's the total number of questions with that tag. Refer to such a link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi

At least this is where I found this issue. At one moment, it read `19,384` questions tagged. Then, at the top, the alert appeared `1 question with new activity`. I did a full refresh of the page, but then the total number was `19,386`. That doesn't add up. Where'd that extra one come from?

Comment: Caching. It's _always_ caching.

Comment: Another question was asked in the time you refreshed? There is caching involved, and who says the notifications are *instant*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to caching. StackOverflow caches the majority of the pages you see, so everything's bound be be a little out of sync of real time. Additionally, the `1 question with new activity` notification isn't instant. It usually turns up 30 seconds to a minute after the question is actually asked.

Additionally, there are cases when you'll see the total number actually going down even though new questions are asked. This is because some of the previously asked questions have been retagged or deleted, thus no longer being counted in the tag total.

Between a combination of the above two points, you're highly likely to get an outdated tag count.